# How can I repair a Windows 7 installation that will work with the upgrade method?

Tags: windows-7, repair-install

I got a computer here that is running Windows Home Premium 64-bit. The machine has something wrong with the networking stack and after everything I am just decided to nuke the system folder and do a repair install.

So I was looking around on google and came across this.

[Windows 7 Repair Install](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html)

So I tried what it said. But I am unable to make this work. When I go through the step I get to the point when I am supposed to click upgrade and fetch the latest files from the Internet. But when I click the last option I am presented with an error that says hey you need to use Anytime Upgrade to do your upgrade. This is probably because the CD I am using is for my main machine which is running Windows 7 Ultimate. The other CD is nowhere to be found so I have to work with what I got.

So... What can I do? I need to reload the machine but because I don't have certain software installers for things installed on this machine I need to keep everything in place yet do the repair.

Can anyone tell what I can do or where I can look for an answer?

Answer (score 0):

The Windows 7 DVDs contain all Windows 7 editions but which edition is used is controlled by a file called `ei.cfg`. Use the [ei.cfg Removal Utility](http://code.kliu.org/misc/winisoutils/) to remove this file and now the upgrade trick should work.

If it still fails, download the Windows 7 ISO from [this legal link](http://msft.digitalrivercontent.net/win/X17-58997.iso) and use it.